# Spring Retry on JPA repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-retry

I am new to spring, as part of my project implementation, I am supposed to add a spring retry on a service method that invokes JPA repository.
Code looks something like below

```
@Retryable(value = {Exception.class},maxAttempts = 1,backoff = @Backoff(300))
public Page<Account> findAllAccounts(AccountSearchRequest account, Pageable pageable) {
    try {
        return map(accountSearchRepository.findAll(account, pageable));
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("SQL EXCEPTION CAUGTH!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    return null;
}
@Recover
public void recover(Exception e){
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!Failed to get connection!!!!!!");
}
```

**Database** : Postgresql,

**Application** : Java Spring Boot (Exposed Rest API to get all accounts)

**HikariPool MaximumPoolSize ** : **1**

**Hikari ConnectionTimeout ** : **1000**

JMeter is used to send **10,000** API requests.

**Problem** : I am able to see **SQL EXCEPTION CAUGTH!!!!!!!!!** prints but i think retry is not working since I am not seeing the recover method's print. am i missing something?

Below is the gradle dependencies

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.retry/spring-retry
compile group: 'org.springframework.retry', name: 'spring-retry', version: '1.2.4.RELEASE'


// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version: '3.2.4.RELEASE'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-aop', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'


// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
```

Comment: You tell Spring to retry if the method throws an exception. But the method never throws an exception, since you catch it. So Spring doesn't retry.

Comment: Hi Nizet, I removed the try catch block but still , im  not able to see the recover method print

Comment: Have you specified `@EnableRetry` on a `@Configuration` class? Why is your `spring-aspects `3.2.4` instead of `5.1.5`? Core springframework jars must all be the same version.

Comment: @Gray Russell i changed to latest version (5.1.5) as you metioned but the result was same.

Comment: in between, is it good idea to have retry policy on JPA methods like save,delete etc ., if so how do we achieve it. @JBNizet

Comment: No, it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the support.

I found the issue was that `@Recover` method had different data type than the `@Retryable`.
Conditions for Retry to work in the above scenario

`@Recover` and `@Retryable` should be public and of the same return type

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Retryable(value = {SQLException.class},maxAttempts = 1,backoff = @Backoff(300))
public Page<Account> findAllAccounts(AccountSearchRequest account, Pageable pageable) throws SQLException {    
       throw new SQLException("test");
}

@Recover
public void recover(Exception e){
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!Failed to get connection!!!!!!");
}
```